# Root element is missing in microsoft xml file

Tags: c#, file, xml-serialization

I try to open `xml` file that I created like this:

```
  public List<MyClass> OpenFile(string path)
        {
            try
            {
                XmlSerializer deserializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<MyClass>));
                TextReader textReader = new StreamReader(path);
                List<MyClass> _newList = (List<MyClass>)deserializer.Deserialize(textReader);
                textReader.Close();
                retrun _newList ;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
```

I get the error: `Root element is missing.`

I saw several places that error appears because the line: `<? Xml version = "1.0"?>` Missing.

I do not understand why it did not work for me, I created the file using the microsoft xml (it worked for me in the past, I added a int variable to my class and then everything went wrong):

```
    public void SaveFile(string path,List<MyClass> list)
    {
        try
        {
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<MyClass>));
            TextWriter textWriter = new StreamWriter(path);
            serializer.Serialize(textWriter,list);
            textWriter.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {

        }

    }
```

What's the problem?

**And to everyone who asks himself, then yes I have this line in the file!**

Comment: Please post the XML (or representative parts, including the start and end). The error has nothing to do with the `<?xml version="1.0"?>` declaration. You probably have more than one [root element](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_element), which is invalid in XML.

Comment: @Oded. But how mistakes can be made ​​while the microsoft xml agreed to create the file without problems?

Comment: How do you know? If there were any exceptions, you have no idea as you have an empty catch block (by the way - **never** do that).

Comment: @Oded I did it just for the deubbger, I do not really use it that way.

Comment: The `XmlSerializer` should have created a single root element, but without seeing the file or the attributes on `MyClass`, I can't tell. The `XmlRootAttribute` may be of use.

Comment: Please post the code of the class(es) you're trying to serialize/deserialize